# How can I use a delimiter in wmic output, separating columns?

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, groovy, wmic

I want to fetch Windows Hotfix listing with some format, whose output can be separated with some delimiter. so far I found a wmic command which gives me a desired output but the problem is the `\s` delimiter is not going to work here. Is there a way I can place some `,` or anyother character, which I can later use in java program to get individual columns?

Command

```
wmic qfe get caption,csname,description,hotfixid,installedby,installedon
```

Output

```
Caption                                        CSName    Description      HotFixID   InstalledBy          InstalledOn
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161784  Abhishek  Update           KB971033   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  3/15/2012
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2032276     Abhishek  Security Update  KB2032276  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  3/15/2012
..
.
```

**Update**

I am trying

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11" %g in ('wmic qfe get caption,csname,description,fixcomments,hotfixid,installdate,installedby,installedon,name,servicepackineffect,status') do @echo %g,%h,%i,%j,%k,%l,%m,%n,%o,%p
```

but it gives me invalid GET Expression

```
C:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop>for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11" %g in ('wmic qfe get caption,csname,description,fixcomments,hotfixid,installdate,installedby,installedon,name,servicepackineffect,status') do @echo %g,%h,%i,%j,%k,%l,%m,%n,%o,%p
Invalid GET Expression.
```

What is the problem here? This might solve the problem for me .

**More Update**

I even tried the below command but this too does not solve space problem

Command

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11" %g in ('wmic qfe list') do @echo %g,%h,%i,%j,%k,%l,%m,%n,%o,%p
```

Output

```
Caption,CSName,Description,FixComments,HotFixID,InstallDate,InstalledBy,InstalledOn,Name,ServicePackInEffect
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161784,Abhishek,Update,KB971033,NT,AUTHOR,,Y\SYSTEM,3/15/2012,
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2281679,Abhishek,Security,Update,KB2281679,NT,AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,3/15/2012,
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2284742,Abhishek,Update,KB2284742,NT,AUTHORIT,,SYSTEM,3/15/2012,
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2286198,Abhishek,Security,Update,KB2286198,NT,AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,3/15/2012,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I can see in the result of wmic, columns are separated ***at least*** by **2 spaces**.

```
Caption                                        CSName    Description      HotFixID   InstalledBy          InstalledOn
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161784  Abhishek  Update           KB971033   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  3/15/2012
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2032276     Abhishek  Security Update  KB2032276  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  3/15/2012
```

So this can be easily parsed in Java by splitting with the `\s{2,}` regular expression :

```
String result = "...";
for (String line : result.split("\n")) {
     System.out.println("-> " + line);
     for (String column : line.split("\\s{2,}")) {
         System.out.println("  => [" + column.trim() + "]");
     }
 }
```

Outputs:

```
-> Caption                                        CSName    Description      HotFixID   InstalledBy          InstalledOn
  => [Caption]
  => [CSName]
  => [Description]
  => [HotFixID]
  => [InstalledBy]
  => [InstalledOn]
-> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161784  Abhishek  Update           KB971033   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  3/15/2012
  => [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161784]
  => [Abhishek]
  => [Update]
  => [KB971033]
  => [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]
  => [3/15/2012]
-> http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2032276     Abhishek  Security Update  KB2032276  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  3/15/2012
  => [http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2032276]
  => [Abhishek]
  => [Security Update]
  => [KB2032276]
  => [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]
  => [3/15/2012]
```

For the batch side, I cannot help you as I know really nothing about it :-)

**Edit:**
Apparently there is a switch `/format:csv` for `wmic` that should generate a CSV that you could also easily parse in Java. I cannot get it to work on my machine, but it's worth to be noticed.

Comment: The problem might still appear if there is only 1 space separating the columns :(

Comment: Yes, but this is not the case in your sample. Besides it would be strange that columns were suddenly separated by only one space, no ? I cannot find anything about the output format of this command, so I can't help you that much. This should work in practice

Comment: See my edit, apparently there is a switch `/format` for wmic.

Comment: I updated with a similar command in my question, thought it might help others to help me. Can you take a look too. Also I do not want to create a file because it will be used on customers machine

Comment: "/format:csv" helped. `wmic qfe list full /format:csv` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did something recently for this type of thing and managed to get it working with the below syntax.  A code snippet below.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims=," %%a IN ('WMIC /NODE:"%PCNAME%" PRODUCT GET 
IDENTIFYINGNUMBER^,INSTALLSOURCE^,NAME^,PACKAGECACHE^,PACKAGENAME^,VENDOR^,VERSION 
/FORMAT:CSV') DO (
 SET ELE1=%%a
 SET ELE2=%%b
 SET ELE3=%%c
 SET ELE4=%%d
 SET ELE5=%%e
 SET ELE6=%%f
 SET ELE7=%%g
 SET ELE8=%%h
 CALL :CheckIt
)
```